# How to get last_updated and newest_blogs in WP 3.0

Tags: plugins, customization, multisite

We were using WPMU version 2.9.1, in which we had a plugin - Fimii WPMU Stats mu-plugin - that showed us last updated blogs, and newest blogs.
We now upgraded to Wodpress 3.0, and the commands for the plugin don't work anymore. Does anyone know of a replacement for that plugin? Or something else that will show the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We found 2 plugins that work:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-recent-posts-widget/
 and http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-recent-posts-widget/